# RabbitMQ Connection reset

Tags: java, rabbitmq

I'm trying to connect a simple RabbitMQ using java code to my server (which is executing the RabbitMQ service).
Executing the following code ([source here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#connecting-without-validating)) gives me the  **java.net.SocketException: Connection Reset** exception.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;


import com.rabbitmq.client.*;

public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("myIP");  //myIP is just dummy text, I have a real IP there
        factory.setPort(5672);
        factory.setUsername("admin");
        factory.setPassword("sesgo");
        factory.setVirtualHost("vSESGO");

        factory.useSslProtocol();

        Connection conn = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = conn.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare("rabbitmq-java-test", false, true, true, null);
        channel.basicPublish("", "rabbitmq-java-test", null, "Hello, World".getBytes());


        GetResponse chResponse = channel.basicGet("rabbitmq-java-test", false);
        if(chResponse == null) {
            System.out.println("No message retrieved");
        } else {
            byte[] body = chResponse.getBody();
            System.out.println("Recieved: " + new String(body));
        }


        channel.close();
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

I've looked for an answer online and I've already tried:

1. Verifying the server has the port I'm connecting to opened.
2. Verifying the client does not block my connection with firewalls, etc.
3. Creating a new Virtual Host on RabbitMQ and giving permissions to it.
4. Verifying iptables is not blocking me at the server side.

Nothing seems to work, any ideas?

Full stacktrace here:

```
This trust manager trusts every certificate, effectively disabling peer verification. This is convenient for local development but prone to man-in-the-middle attacks. Please see http://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html#validating-cerficates to learn more about peer certificate validation.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(Unknown Source)
 at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:147)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.sendHeader(SocketFrameHandler.java:153)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:294)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:63)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:99)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:921)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:880)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:838)
 at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:990)
 at test.main(test.java:25)
```

Comment: Give the full stack trace error

Comment: When you created the connection, do you have an error on this or at the creation of a channel ?

Comment: Based on the debugger the line that gives me the error is the one that creates the connection:
Connection conn = factory.newConnection();

Comment: So verify the informations you give like the host and port (It isn't localhost for the host ?)

Comment: I've written "myIp" there because I have my server's real ip in my code.

Comment: factory.useSslProtocol(); this line may cause issue. ssl is a big mesh in java!!!!

Comment: Do you have access to the RabbitMQ server? If so, could you retrieve the logs - make sure that you have a queue connected to exchange amq.rabbitmq.log, binding "#" to get all log messages.

Comment: You need to first try this without TLS/SSL. If that works, follow the instructions in this guide: https://www.rabbitmq.com/troubleshooting-ssl.html

Comment: I do have access to the server.  I'm configuring both the client and the server.

The connection is working without TLS/SSL.  I'll try following that guide.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue right here: [RabbitMQ Connection reset Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61941965/rabbitmq-connection-reset-exception). Solution for Windows was to add backslash in rabbit config file for paths to certs and key.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this applies to your situation, but I recently resolved a similar situation while testing RabbitMQ 3.8.3, and the cause was that the key I was referencing was password-protected, but I had failed to provide the password in the RabbitMQ config, like this:

```
ssl_options.password = password
```

Unfortunately there was absolutely nothing in the RabbitMQ logs about this, even with the log level set to debug. When testing via various clients, a connection was established, but RabbitMQ immediately sent a connection reset.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same error and my issue was in the rabbitmq.conf file. I was trying to use a JKS file for the following ssl options. Generating my own self signed .pem files was able to help fix this. I followed this guide pretty closely https://www.codetd.com/en/article/12031242.

```
ssl_options.cacertfile = /etc/rabbitmq/ca_certificate.pem
ssl_options.certfile   = /etc/rabbitmq/server_certificate.pem
ssl_options.keyfile    = /etc/rabbitmq/server_key.pem
```